# Can you connect a SqlActivity to a JdbcDatabase in Amazon Data Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using Amazon Data Pipeline, I'm trying to use a SqlActivity to execute some SQL on a non-Redshift data store (SnowflakeDB, for the curious).  It seems like it should be possible to do that with a [SqlActivity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-sqlactivity.html) that uses a [JdbcDatabase](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-jdbcdatabase.html). My first warning was when the wysiwyg editor on Amazon didn't even let me try to create a JdbcDatabase, but I plowed on anyway and just wrote and uploaded a Json definition by hand, myself (here's the relevant bit):

```
{
  "id" : "ExportToSnowflake",
  "name" : "ExportToSnowflake",
  "type" : "SqlActivity",
  "schedule" : { "ref" : "DefaultSchedule" },
  "database" : { "ref" : "SnowflakeDatabase" },
  "dependsOn" : { "ref" : "ImportTickets" },
  "script" : "COPY INTO ZENDESK_TICKETS_INCREMENTAL_PLAYGROUND FROM @zendesk_incremental_stage"
},
{
  "id" : "SnowflakeDatabase",
  "name" : "SnowflakeDatabase",
  "type" : "JdbcDatabase",
  "jdbcDriverClass" : "com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver",
  "username" : "redacted",
  "connectionString" : "jdbc:snowflake://redacted.snowflakecomputing.com:8080/?account=redacted&db=redacted&schema=PUBLIC&ssl=on",
  "*password" : "redacted"
}
```

When I upload this into the designer, it refuses to activate, giving me this error message:

```
ERROR: 'database' values must be of type 'RedshiftDatabase'. Found values of type 'JdbcDatabase'
```

The rest of the pipeline definition works fine without any errors.  I've confirmed that it activates and runs to success if I simply leave this step out.

I am unable to find a single mention on the entire Internet of someone actually using a JdbcDatabase from Data Pipeline.  Does it just plain not work?  Why is it even mentioned in the documentation if there's no way to actually use it?  Or am I missing something?  I'd love to know if this is a futile exercise before I blow more of the client's money trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? I have the same question. Considering giving up an just using a non-data-pipeline solution.

Comment: haven't gotten an answer.  I ended up talking the client into using Amazon Simple Workflow instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your `JdbcDatabase` you need to have the following property:

```
jdbcDriverJarUri: "[S3 path to the driver jar file]"
```